# ParseCrashReporting-*.jar is not found on 1.11.0 of its Android SDK

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I'm following the [ParseCrashReporting installation tutorial](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/crashreporting/android/existing) on Parse website. It says that I need to download the Parse SDK and copy the ParseCrashReporting-*.jar. However, the jar is not found inside the zip file. The version of the SDK is 1.11.0. Where can I find the latest version of the jar file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an announcement Parse sent two days ago. Parse crash reporting is being deprecated.

[image: No crash Reporting]